# s3 images not loading after copying it from one bucket to another of same account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I have copied images from one bucket to another and now i am unable to access images. Error shows 
`AccessDenied` message.

I have verified file exists in bucket but unable to access it. If i remove same image and upload it again then it is working.

Please suggest any reason if anything i missed during copying bucket data from one to another.

Link which was working with old bucket and now not accessible with new bucket

```
https://abc.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/profile/image/16923/client_thumb_CINDERELLA_12
```

Comment: do you have the same bucket policy as the previous one? click on the image and check what permissions do you have on it and verify it with the images on the first bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy (or whatever put action) in S3 is by default private because that's the deault ACL behavior, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl). This is why you get access denied even though the source file has public access enabled. Therefore you need to specify the ACL to `public-read` during the copy, in your case (cli sample):

```
aws s3 cp s3://mySourceBucket/test.txt s3://myDestinationBucket/test.txt --acl public-read
```

Note that according to AWS, if you use `--acl`, your IAM policy must include the `S3:PutObjectAcl` action.

> --acl (string) Sets the ACL for the object when the command is performed. If you use this parameter you must have the "s3:PutObjectAcl" permission included in the list of actions for your IAM policy. Only accepts values of private, public-read, public-read-write, authenticated-read, aws-exec-read, bucket-owner-read, bucket-owner-full-control and log-delivery-write. See Canned ACL for details

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the public URL for the S3 object and it works only if you open the bucket publically. You have to set your new bucket publically accessible and **ALSO** set the bucket policy such as:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

where the `examplebucket` is the name for the bucket.